# Extract Data from Excel Spreadsheet into Database in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, import-from-excel

I'm looking to extract quite a lot of data from spreadsheets for a Rails application, but I'm doing the extraction through the Rails Console.

I have a table called `instititutes` in my database which currently has around 170 records. I've found far better data in a spreadsheet with c.1000 records and want to import that to my database, but to skip any records that match already.

I thought that using the find_or_create_by method would be the best move for this. The spreadsheet has `UKPRN` and `NAME` as headers, and the table has `ukprn` and `name` as respective columns (as well as others).

Using the Roo gem, I've got this so far:

```
require 'roo'

xlsx = Roo::Spreadsheet.open(File.expand_path('../Downloads/UKPRN.xlsx'))
xlsx.default_sheet = xlsx.sheets.last
header = xlsx.row(1)
xlsx.each_row do |row|
    row = Institute.find_or_create_by(UKPRN: ukprn , NAME: name)
end
```

This is giving the error `NameError: unitialized constant UKPRN`. I'm still getting my head back into Ruby so any help would be appreciated.

I'm using Ruby 2.2.3 and Rails 5.0.1

Edit:

`p row` shows:

```
["UKPRN", "NAME"]
[10000291, "Anglia Ruskin University"]
[10000385, "The Arts University Bournemouth"]
[10000571, "Bath Spa University"]
[10000712, "University College Birmingham"]
[10000824, "Bournemouth University"]
[10000886, "The University of Brighton"]
[10000961, "Brunel University London"]
...etc
```

Comment: What does `p row` output inside `each_row`? Without the `row = Institute...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table has `ukprn` and `name` as respective columns, so `find_or_create` should look like :

```
Institute.find_or_create_by(ukprn: ukprn , name: name)
```

Now you just need to initialize `ukprn` and `name` from `row`.

```
require 'roo'

xlsx = Roo::Excelx.new(File.expand_path('../Downloads/UKPRN.xlsx'))

xlsx.each_row_streaming(offset: 1) do |row|
  Institute.find_or_create_by(ukprn: row[0].value, name: row[1].value)
end
```

To execute this code, either :

- put it in `db/seeds.rb` and execute `rake db:seed`
- put it in `script.rb` and run `rails runner script.rb`
- copy-paste it in console (not really recommended)

Comment: Apologies, but what would be the best way to do this from the console?